# Dynamically add file input to form

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, input, attachment

I am working on an email script that is able to send multiple attachments. Currently I just have 3 file inputs in it which look like this:

[image: translated: select a file/no file selected and Verstuur = Send]

*translated:* <kbd>Select a file</kbd> **No file selected** *and Verstuur =* <kbd>Send</kbd>

The script itself works fine and it is able to send multiple attachments but I would like to have just 1 file input to select a file and create a button or a link which will add another file input so the user himself can select as many attachments as he needs. I have searched on this forum and on google and I found out that it is possible using jquery. I have never used jquery before and I can't figure out how to do it by myself. If someone can explain how to do it or has any tips it would be great.

The html form I have now basicly included this now:

```
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]"><br/>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]"><br/>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Verstuur" name="submit" ><br/>
```

***Edit***: I got it figured out using [this](http://edrupler.com/jQuery%E2%80%93Dynamically-Adding-Form-Elements)

Comment: I have two great tips. 1. Learn Javascript (would be enough to do the job). 2. Learn jQuery (makes it even easier to do the job). In this profession you have to learn new things all the time. Even if other people do it for you a few times, you will still need this knowledge in the future.

Comment: The problem is that I just need it for this small thing and since I am a student and currently an trainee I have no time to learn everything.

Comment: Then just don't do it. Inserting a half-engineered solution that you know nothing about will cause a lot of problems for you... in the end, you will lose more time than you would have spent on learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
<input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

See this:

```
$("#attach").on("change", " input[type=file]:last", function(){
    var item = $(this).clone(true);
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    if(fileName){
       $(this).parent().append("<br/>").append(item);
    }  
});
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/E4PWH/2/)**